# how to select elements when the root element has a lot of attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, gbxml

I have following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<gbXML version="0.37" useSIUnitsForResults="true" volumeUnit="CubicMeters" areaUnit="SquareMeters" lengthUnit="Meters" temperatureUnit="C" xmlns="http://www.gbxml.org/schema" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.gbxml.org/schema xsi.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Campus id="cmps-1">
<Location>
<Name>Trois-Rivieres, PQ Canada</Name>
<Latitude>46.210000</Latitude>
<Longitude>-72.350000</Longitude>
</Location>
</Campus>
</gbXML>
```

I want to select the "Latitude" value.
I am using the below XPath expression which is not returning anything:

```
<p><code><xsl:value-of select="gbXML/Campus/Location/Latitude"/></code></p>
```

I am new in XPath, I will really appreciate it if someone could help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a default namespace `xmlns="http://www.gbxml.org/schema"`.

In your XSLT, just add another namespace, say `xmlns:text="xmlns="http://www.gbxml.org/schema"` (you are creating a shortcut of the default namespace).

Add also `exclude-result-prefixes="text"` to omit the `text` prefix in the output.

Then, change:

```
<p><code><xsl:value-of select="gbXML/Campus/Location/Latitude"/></code></p>
```

to

```
<p><code><xsl:value-of select="text:gbXML/text:Campus/text:Location/text:Latitude"/></code></p>
```

Comment: Hi again, I am new to XSLT, like I mentioned before. I was just wondering can I use the expression xsl:for-each select=""> more than once in my XSLT and how? Thank you I will really appreciate your help with that –

Comment: Please create another question with sample input XML and the required output. State there that you want something achieved using xsl:for-each.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the namespace declaration in xpath. Declare the namespace in the stylesheet and then use the prefix in the xpath:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:gb="http://www.gbxml.org/schema">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <p><code><xsl:value-of select="gb:gbXML/gb:Campus/gb:Location/gb:Latitude"/></code></p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works now!. I am using oXigen to validate my XSLT style sheet

Comment: I want to accept both answers because both answers worked but I can only accept one apparently :s

Comment: Hi again, I am new to XSLT, like I mentioned before. I was just wondering can I use the expression xsl:for-each select=""> more than once in my XSLT and how? Thank you I will really appreciate your help with that

Comment: Can you post a new question for the same? This way you can give us more details about your requirement and more chances of getting better answers.